# Error in retrieving value from JSON response in bash scripting using python

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to retrieve the value of 'Token' from JSON response in bash scripting. I can use in-built code such as grep or I can use python to parse the JSON response. However, I should not use external dependencies such as jq tool.

I used the following python code to retrieve the value of 'Token'. FYI, I am using Git tool to run the bash script from my windows machine and I have installed python3.9 from Microsoft Store.

```
loginResponse=$(curl -X POST --header ....)
val2=echo $loginResponse|python3 -c "import sys;import json;print(json.load(sys.stdin)['Token'])"
```

Following error message is thrown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Logged In Successfully. Authentication Token=
root@LAPTOP-FAOR3D6:/mnt/c/Users/BellSys/Desktop/Bash# bash pipeline.sh
```

I figured out that this issue occurs specifically with sys.stdin, because I ran a separate python script with the following json.load code and it worked fine. So, I am not sure whether it's the module issue w.r.t sys package.

```
# Opening JSON file
f = open('JSONResponse.json',)
print(json.load(f)['Token'])
```

Comment: why not use jq if you're going to manipulate json in a bash script?

Comment: or, why not do the whole thing in python, request included?

Comment: The purpose is to integrate my script in the CI/CD pipeline. Retrieving the json is just a part of the whole script and the requirement is to write in shell. So I can neither include jq tool nor write the full scripts in python

Comment: verify that `loginResponse` contains what you expect, because `echo '{"Token": "foo"}'|python3 -c "import sys;import json;print(json.load(sys.stdin)['Token'])"` outputs `foo`, as expected.